# Can an XML document have 2 elements with the same id or not?

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2, ebxml

I'm trying to integrate an Android application with a SOAP webservice using kSoap2. I manage to make a request and get some data back but when response parsing happens, I have the following RuntimeException:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: double ID
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.resolveReference(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:462)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:439)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.serialization.ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.read(ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:86)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:304)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.serialization.ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:93)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:434)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.serialization.ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.read(ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:86)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:304)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.serialization.ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:93)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:434)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.serialization.ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.read(ExSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:86)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:146)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.mtom.MTOMSoapSerializationEnvelope.parse(MTOMSoapSerializationEnvelope.java:70)
                  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
                  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:304)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.transport.AdvancedHttpsTransportSE.parseResponse(AdvancedHttpsTransportSE.java:35)
                  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:276)
                  at com.easywsdl.exksoap2.transport.AdvancedHttpsTransportSE.call(AdvancedHttpsTransportSE.java:51)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.sendRequest(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:102)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.execute(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:181)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQuery(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:147)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12$2.Func(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:168)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12$2.Func(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:166)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12$3.doInBackground(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:218)
                  at be.brusafe.brusafeplus.xds.iti18.DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12$3.doInBackground(DocumentRegistry_Binding_Soap12.java:207)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And indeed, in the response, I have 2 elements with different types but with the same value for their id attribute.

```
<ExtrinsicObject home="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.48336.1" id="urn:uuid:3468543d-5033-4d6b-86a5-f8a52fd0070e"
    isOpaque="false"
    lid="urn:uuid:3468543d-5033-4d6b-86a5-f8a52fd0070e"
    mimeType="text/xml"
    objectType="urn:uuid:7edca82f-054d-47f2-a032-9b2a5b5186c1"
    status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved">
```

And:

```
<ObjectRef home="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.48336.1"
    id="urn:uuid:3468543d-5033-4d6b-86a5-f8a52fd0070e" />
```

I don't develop the SOAP webservice myself so I told the developers that I don't understand how that's possible because I thought the XML specification itself said IDs had to be unique. And this is what they answered:

> In this case it is possible because the atribbute "id" isn't the data
>   type "ID" but the data type "URN". The atribbute is refering to a
>   unique id in the registry and it isn't an id of the element it self. 
>   In this application, we are using ebXML Registry Information Model
>   Version 3.0 as default. You can find more information and examples in
>   the document of oasis:
>   https://docs.oasis-open.org/regrep/v3.0/specs/regrep-rim-3.0-os.pdf

And now I'm confused. So can there be several elements with the same ID in an XML document or not? And if yes, is there a way to configure kSOAP2 to make it ignore that double ID?

Answer (score 0):

An XML document with duplicate ID values is well-formed but not valid. An XML parser will read such a document successfully if it is running as a non-validating parser.

I don't know the library you are using to do the parsing so I have no idea whether it is possible to disable validation, or to ignore the validation errors.

Comment: Even if those elements define their id attribute of type anyURI and not XSD:ID in the XML schema? (cf. https://github.com/oehf/ipf/blob/8a22c51a47fab1af6fea7da81f9e5d8de636e225/commons/ihe/xds/src/main/resources/wsdl/schema/ebRS30/rim.xsd#L103)

Comment: The question wasn't explicit, but I understood it to be using "ID" in the sense of the `ID` attribute type in DTDs, the `xs:ID` type in XSD, or the `xml:id` attribute. Of course if it's any old attribute that just happens to be named "id" then it has no uniqueness semantics.